# Prove $\arctan(x)$ can be estimated by $\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{1}{x}$ when $x$ is large

Tags: calculus

What I tried:
Let $f(x)= \arctan(x)$, then by mean value theorem, $\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=f'(a)$, where $0<a<x$. So $f(x)=f'(a)x=\frac{x}{1+a^2}$.
I don't know where to go from here, and there is a hint to use $\frac{\pi}{2}- \arctan(x)= \arctan\left( \frac{1}{x} \right)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Recall (from the geometric series) that, for $|x|<1$:
$$\frac{1}{1+x^2}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty(-1)^nx^{2n}$$
Integrate this to get a series expansion for $\arctan(x)$, and conclude that $\arctan(x)\approx x$ for small $x$. What does this tell you about the behavior of $\arctan$ for large values of $x$ (or equivalently, small values of $1/x$)?

Comment: Thanks, is it then to use $\frac{\pi}{2}- \arctan(x)= \arctan(x) \left( \frac{1}{x} \right)$ to get when $x$ is small, then$1/x$ is large, so $\arctan(1/x)=\pi/2-x$, then let $x=1/x$ to get the conclusion? And is it possible to use mean value theorem along to get the conclusion? The question kind of requiring that.

Comment: Essentially yes. If you write $\arctan(x)=\pi/2-\arctan(1/x)$, then $\arctan(x)\approx\pi/2-1/x$ when $1/x$ is small/$x$ is large. Alternatively, using the mean value theorem, for small $x$, you have $\arctan(x)=x/(1+a^2)$, where $a$ is between $0$ and $x$; if $x$ is small, then $a$ must also be small, and so $x/(1+a^2)\approx x$. That should get you a similar conclusion.

Comment: Just for the $x/(1+a^2)\approx x$ part, is it basically when $a$ is small, then $a^2$ is small, then $x/(1+a^2)$ basically $x/1=x$? But can this part be proved a little more rigorously?

Comment: You could Taylor expand and say $x/(1+a^2)=x(1-a^2+a^4+\cdots)$, which is more obviously close to $x$ when $a\approx 0$. But you are making an estimate, which is not a particularly rigorous process anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Using the hint $\frac{\pi}{2}- \arctan(x) = \arctan\left( \frac{1}{x} \right)$ combined with $\arctan(t) \approx t$ when $t$ is close to $0$:
$$
\arctan(x) 
= \frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan\left( \frac{1}{x} \right)
\approx \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{1}{x}
.
$$
when $x$ is big.